# Better interface for composing destructive operators

Tags: haskell

I've got the following code in an old project of mine:

```
-- |ImageOperation is a name for unary operators that mutate images inplace.
newtype ImageOperation c d = ImgOp (Image c d-> IO ())

-- |Compose two image operations
(#>) :: ImageOperation c d-> ImageOperation c d -> ImageOperation c d
(#>) (ImgOp a) (ImgOp b) = ImgOp (\img -> (a img >> b img))

-- |An unit operation for compose 
nonOp = ImgOp (\i -> return ())

-- |Apply image operation to a Copy of an image
img <# op = unsafeOperate op img

-- | Apply the operation on a clone of an image
operate (ImgOp op) img = withClone img $ \clone -> 
                                           op clone >> return clone

unsafeOperate op img = unsafePerformIO $ operate op img
```

Its main purpose is to allow composition of opencv operators that run in place and accept an image of the same format and a dimension. It is an important optimization, since for example, without it drawing 100 lines would allocate the 1mb image hundred times. The current interface works nicely but I have a feeling that there might be a some standard approach to doing thing like this. So,

1. Am I doing something that appears elsewhere with standardized name?
2. Can I do this better?
3. Can this approach be generalized for binary operators in a way that doesn't allow unsafe references to specific states of the mutable image?

**Edit:**
An example of a binary operation is 'take an image, make a blurred copy and subtract from the original. Return the result'.  The effective version with minimal copies in just the IO monad would be something like:

```
poorMansHighPass img = do
    x <- clone img
    gaussian (5,5) x
    subtract x img
    return x
```

Although I can make an operator like this, I would much prefer something that is more of a composition of primitive operators than ugly bit of unsafe io code.

Comment: A) An image operation is a monoid -- it has a zero, and it has composition. B) Is `unsafeOperate` actually unsafe? It uses mutation under the covers, but should appear ref transparent to anyone invokin it.

Comment: A) Thanks, B) yeah, it is not unsafe. Just badly named.

Comment: Isn't your example just `poorMansHighPass img = img <# ('subtract' img) 'mplus' gaussian (5,5)`? (single quotes should be backticks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I can at least point out what to call some of the patterns you're using currently.

So we have a type representing a reference to some mutable data, and a type representing opaque operations on it. We also have a null op and a composition function, which gives an obvious `Monoid` instance:

```
instance Monoid (ImageOperation c d) where
    mempty = nonOp
    mappend = (#>)
```

So that's at least one standard name you could use.

Further, the above `Monoid` is actually a straightforward result of the properties of two other well-known types:

- The `Applicative` and/or `Monad` instance for `(->) a` describes combining functions by applying all of them to a single argument, as with the image in the composition function. Basically a lightweight, in-line version of the `Reader` monad.
- The `Monad` instance for `IO`, or rather the monoidal structure it implies. By fixing `IO`'s type parameter to `()`, the monad laws reduce to a simple monoid, with `return ()` as unit and `(>>)` as the monoid operation.

To reconstruct your combination, given two functions (unwrapped `ImageOperation`s) and imagining that the implied monoid for `IO ()` is an actual instance, we could write:

```
nonOp = pure mempty

x #> y = mappend <$> x <*> y
```

It's also worth noting that the combination of something like a reader monad and a monad allowing mutable state essentially describes "a surrounding environment with mutable references", a.k.a. mutable global variables, except that "global" here means "within a single computation of the combined monad". I've actually constructed such a monad explicitly, using `ReaderT` and `STM`.

That handles combining operations. To actually run an operation, you need an `Image` and I'm gathering you want to only operate on clones, the creation of which is inefficient. Fortunately, considering how very general the above construction for the `Monoid` is, there's really nothing you can't cram into an `ImageOperation` before actually running it. Generating the clone is presumably an `IO` operation and is what I assume is going on in `operate`--there's probably not really any other way to do that.

Beyond that, if you're interested in alternate ways to structure the whole thing, one obvious variant would be to wrap `Image` instead into something representing the process of constructing one, with operators merged in to transform the image being produced using something like `operate`. I don't know if this would actually gain you anything, though.

In fact, I'm inclined to doubt that there're really any other ways to do this. You're writing an FFI binding to a highly imperative library and there's only so much you can do to disguise that.

I'm not sure, however, why you have an unsafe version of `operate`. What practical purpose would this serve?

I'm also not sure what kind of binary operators you'd like to generalize this to--there's not much else you can do operating on `ImageOperation` besides what you have here. Do you mean generalizing `ImageOperation` to work on more than one mutable reference to an image? Or something involving operations on images that return something other than just `IO ()`?

---

**EDIT**: Okay, let's look at how one might decompose `poorMansHighPass`. Hopefully I'm correctly reading what it's doing here:

First, `gaussian` is independent and can be factored out as its own operation: `gauss' = ImgOp . gaussian`.

Next, `subtract` can also be factored out, parameterized by an additional `Image`: `subtr' = ImgOp . flip subtract`.

These two are the core of the function, and they can be combined in the usual manner: `poorMansHP' img =  gauss' (5, 5) #> subtr' img`. The last thing needed to recover the original function is that the `img` argument given to `poorMansHP'` must be the *same* image whose clone is passed to the inner function by `operate`.

First we'll explicitly unwrap the `ImageOperation` and use that in the reimplementation:

```
poorMansHighPass img = 
    let (ImgOp op) = gauss' (5, 5) #> subtr' img
    in do x <- clone img
          op x
          return x
```

Substitute `withClone` for the use of `clone` here:

```
poorMansHighPass img = 
    let (ImgOp op) = gauss' (5, 5) #> subtr' img
    in withClone img $ \x -> do op x
                                return x
```

Desugar the `do` block:

```
poorMansHighPass img = 
    let (ImgOp op) = gauss' (5, 5) #> subtr' img
    in withClone img $ \x -> op x >> return x
```

...which obviously contains a reimplementation of `operate`, so replace that and simplify:

```
poorMansHighPass img = operate (gauss' (5, 5) #> subtr' img) img
```

More interesting would be implementing `poorMansHighPass` in a way that modifies the argument instead of the clone, which would allow it to be packaged up as an `ImageOperation` itself. Possibly that's what it's supposed to be doing, and I misread your code?

Anyway, the basic structure of the refactoring would be the same, but you'd need a different composition operator--instead of applying two operators to the same input in sequence, it would need to create a clone of the input internally before recombining the results. I have a rough idea what kind of structure would make this work smoothly, which I can elaborate on if you'd like but I'll have to work through it a bit to make sure it behaves properly.

Comment: Thanks for excellent answer. I added a clarification of binary operators to the question.

Comment: (The badly named unsafe version of operate is there for pretty much the same reason as you have runST.)

Comment: @aleator: Added some stuff to the answer based on your edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/982393) is the approach I took with OpenCV code. I never saw it beyond what I needed for a couple projects I was working on, and I think this kind of approach should come with performance regression tests.