# Better interface for composing destructive operators, Part II

Tags: haskell, combinators

See my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059505/better-interface-for-composing-destructive-operators) about composing opencv operators for an explanation of what is going on.

I thought up a new interface that allows to compose destructive binary operations in a kind of composable way:

```
newtype IOP a b = IOP (a -> IO b)

instance Category IOP where
    id = IOP return
    (IOP f) . (IOP g)  = IOP $ g >=> f

(&#&) :: IOP (Image c d) e -> IOP (Image c d) f 
             -> IOP (Image c d) (Image c d,Image c d)
(IOP f) &#& (IOP g) = IOP $ op
    where 
        op i = withClone i $ \cl -> (f i >> g cl >> return (i,cl))

runIOP (IOP f) img = withClone img f
```

With this I can easily express the 'subtract the gaussian operator':

```
subtract  :: IOP (Image c d, Image c1 d1) (Image c d)
mulScalar :: d -> IOP (Image c d) (Image c d)
subtractScalar :: d -> IOP (Image c d) (Image c d)
gaussian  :: (Int, Int) -> IOP (Image GrayScale D32) (Image GrayScale D32)

(gaussian (11,11) &#& id) >>> subtract >>> mulScalar 5
```

To me this seems like a quite safe alternative, though it is not optimal in the sense, that it probably could re-use also the cloned image if some operation after subtract would require this. But it still seems like an acceptable alternative to the completely pure and unoptimized version:

```
mulScalar 5 $ gaussian (11,11) img `subtract` img
-- Or with nicer names for the operators
5 * gaussian (11,11) img - img
```

**Questions**

1. Is this a reasonable structure in the first place?
2. Is there a reason to prefer the structure in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059505/better-interface-for-composing-destructive-operators)?
3. How would you extend this to implement an operation 'find the minimum value in the image, subtract it from the image and then multiply the image with its range (i.e max-min).'
4. Should I split these into multiple questions instead?

Comment: Just some comments: `f >>= return = f`, `\ clone -> f clone = f`.

Comment: @augustss Doh. Of course. I'm just not a morning person it seems :)

Comment: Also, `IOP` is the same as `Kleisli IO`, which gets you the `Category` instance (and others) for free.

Comment: As a brief follow-up to my answer in the previous question, which ended up poorly organized as I tried to get a sense of what you were aiming for: The alternate structure I mentioned having in mind at the end is pretty close to either `Kleisli IO` or what @sclv describes, plus using either `Arrow` combinators or a reader monad to describe some sort of "clone" operator. I wasn't confident that it correctly expressed the performance characteristics, however, and @sclv's simpler approach should get the job done nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from hammar's comment, you can just use kleisli composition to begin with, avoiding the IOP altogether. I've kept ImageOp as a type synonym for clarity's sake. Also, I specialized it to always return unit, and changed some other type signatures accordingly so that we have a typed difference between mutating functions (returning unit) and cloining functions (returning a new value), and a function `apOp` that applies a mutating function and returns the mutated value so that we can chain mutations easily.

```
type ImageOp c d -> Image c d -> IO ()

(&#&) :: ImageOp c d -> ImageOp c d -> (Image c d) -> IO (Image c d, Image c d)
f &#& g = \i -> withClone i $ \cl -> f i >> g cl >> return (i,cl)

apOp :: ImageOp c d -> Image c d -> IO (Image c d)
apOp iop x = fmap x (iop x)

subtract  ::  Image c d ->  ImageOp c1 d1
mulScalar :: d -> ImageOp (Image c d)
subtractScalar :: d -> ImageOp (Image c d)
gaussian  :: (Int, Int) -> ImageOp GrayScale D32

myFun = (gaussian (11,11) &#& id) >=> (\(x,y) -> apOp (subtract x) y) >=> apOp (mulScalar 5) 

--pointfree
myFun = (gaussian (11,11) &#& id) >=> uncurry (apOp . subtract) >=> apOp (mulScalar 5)
```

**Edit**
If you feel like it, you can write `&#&` neatly as follows:

```
f &#& g = uncurry (liftM2 (,)) . (apOp f &&& withClone (apOp g))
```

Which, I think, is a good argument for this style being pretty expressive.

Comment: On the other hand, the benefit of using `Kleisli IO` is getting all the bonus instances, most notably `Arrow` and company, which may or may not be preferable to the approach you give here.

Comment: @camccann -- I don't see Arrow and Category as buying you almost anything in this case. I suppose they lend themselves to a slightly more straightforward pipeline style (`&#&` can be written without the `liftM2 (,)` that I provide in my above edit) but the newtyping adds plenty of friction points as well. Generally, I think the kleisli composition operators (`<=<`, `>=>`) don't get nearly as much use as they should.

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking. In particular, the pipeline style is nice but would work at cross purposes with the typed distinction between mutate/clone operations you have here, which have much more obvious value. It's unfortunate we can't write the instances without a `newtype` and thereby use both, but there's no way to express functor composition directly.

Comment: @camccann Thanks for excellent suggestions for my really vague question. However, I think that dropping the newtype allows the user of the library to make mistakes like `(\x -> gaussian (11,11) x >>= \y -> subtract x y)` too easily. But I think I have enough clues to carry on now :)

Comment: @aleator -- the typed distinction between mutating ops (returning unit) and cloning ops (returning an image) means that your above example is ill-typed and will be caught.